# Understanding Apache Camel routing for Amazon SQS

Tags: apache-camel, apache-camel-aws

I have an SQS queue. The objective that I am looking to accomplish is to filter message based upon message attributes and delete the same if it matches the filter criteria. So I have a function in Java which looks something like this

```java
public String getUri(){
    String uri = String.format("aws-sqs://%s?accessKey=%s&secretKey=%s&attributeNames=test&deleteIfFiltered=true",queueUrl,key,secret)
    return uri;
}
```

Post this I am calling this function

```java
public Builder extends RouteBuilder{

    @Override
    public void configure(){
        try{
            from(getUri())
            .setHeader()
            ...
        }

    }
```

It looks like the route that is building is not able to delete the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do as in the documentation says: https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/aws2-sqs-component.html

about the *deleteIfFiltered* option.

You need to set the exchange property (not header) with key `CamelAwsSqsDeleteFiltered` to `true`.

See the docs and this example:
https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/aws2-sqs-component.html#_jms_style_selectors

Comment: Iam still using camel 2.7 owing to constraints. I believe I cannot set the properties there